# Pandas multiple index dataframe: creating new index or appending to existing index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a Pandas dataframe, `multi_df`, which has a multi-index made of the `code`,`colour`,`texture` and `shape` values as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                    'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                                'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                    'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                            'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                    'texture': ['soft', 'soft', 'hard','soft','hard',
                                        'hard','hard','hard'],
                    'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular','triangular','square',
                                        'triangular','round','triangular'],
                    'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','code','colour', 'texture', 'shape', 'amount'])
multi_df = df.set_index(['code','colour','texture','shape']).sort_index()['id']
multi_df
code   colour  texture  shape     
one    black   soft     round         1
       white   hard     round         7
               soft     triangular    2
three  black   hard     triangular    6
       white   soft     triangular    4
two    black   hard     square        5
       white   hard     triangular    3
                        triangular    8
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

I am given a `new index` - `new_id` couple. If the `new_index` (combination) already exists in the `multi_df`, I want to append the `new_id` to the existing index. If the `new_index` does not exist, I want to create it and add the id value. For instance:

```
new_id = 15
new_index = ('two','white','hard', 'triangular')
if new_index in multi_df.index:
    # APPEND TO EXISTING: multi_df[('two','white','hard', 'triangular')].append(new_id)
else:
    # CREATE NEW index and put the new_id in.
```

However, I cannot figure out the syntax for appending `(IF)` or creating `(ELSE)` the new index. Any help would be most welcome.

P.S: for appending I can see that the object that I am trying to add the `new_id` to is a `Series`. However, append() does not work..

```
type(multi_df[('two','white','hard', 'triangular')])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score 2):

`append()` creates a new series every time, so it's very slow, if you need call this in a for loop:

```
data = pd.Series(15, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('two','white','hard', 'triangular')]))
multi_df.append(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, is there an alternative to using `append()` then?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you want to do. Where does the data come from, what kind of data processing you want?